# リスト内リストの要素を削除したい

Tags: python

初めて質問いたします。

```
A =[[a,b,c],[d,e,f],[g,h,i]]
```

上記のようなリストがあります。
それぞれのリスト内リストの０番目（aとdとg）を削除したいのですが、どのような処理をすればよいのでしょうか。

```
del A[?][0]
```

のように書いたら可能なのでしょうか。

勉強不足で至らないところも多いですが、何卒よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: numpy を使ってもよいのであれば `import numpy as np` としておいて `A = np.array(A)[:,1:].tolist()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

この記事を参考に：
[Pythonのスライスによるリストや文字列の部分選択・代入](https://note.nkmk.me/python-slice-usage/)

こんな風に出来ます。
A自身を変えたいならAに代入。
変えたものをAとは別にしたいならその別の物(例えばB)に代入。

```
A = [row[1:] for row in A]
```